# When inbound class used in Web service Object Structure is called in IBM Maximo?

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

I have an Object structure of a Web Service in IBM Maximo which has inbound processing class attached to it. I am not getting when this will be called as the source object is in my database(on which object structure has been made) ,this object gets data from different  tables of my database itself.

The inbound class updates the data of the object structure's object.

Comment: If you don't want that bounty to go to waste, add your code and more details. As it stands this is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A processing class has a few different hooks into the code flow of an integration, depending on which specific method you override. Generally, there is one method that allows you access (and modify) the XML data and structure before MBOs are created from that data, and one method that allows you to access and modify the MBOs that were created from the inbound data.

Maximo will on its own (without a processing class) already take the inbound data XML and map it to the various fields on the various MBOs listed on the Object Structure and then "save" those MBOs (persist the records to the database). The inbound processing class is mostly just to let you modify that data before or after (depending on which method you override) the data is mapped to the fields on the MBOs, but in either case before it is save to the database.